# Is there any way to get at the container template type to reuse it with another value_type?

Tags: c++, templates, containers, c++17

I have a function template parametrized on `typename ContainerType` which accepts a `const ContainerType&` parameter. It converts each element inside the container to some other type and (currently) returns an `std::vector` of the converted type.

Is there any way I can "borrow" the actual outer class template of the deduced `ContainerType`?
I currently have [this code returning the hardcoded `vector`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71ba610d6e5453ab):

```
template<typename ContainerType, typename OutputType = decltype(convert(std::declval<typename ContainerType::value_type>()))>
std::vector<OutputType> convert(const ContainerType& input)
{
  std::vector<OutputType> result;
  result.reserve(input.size());
  std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(result),
                 static_cast<OutputType(*)(typename ContainerType::value_type)>(&convert));
  return result;
}
```

I'd like to deduce the class template stripped only from its `value_type`. Remember that containers typically have more than 1 template argument (and the amount differs by container and implementation), so a template template parameter for `ContainerType` is not a solution here.

Comment: The body is specific to `vector`. What do you expect it to do for other container types?

Comment: @Barry it is specific to containers with `reserve` and a `back_insert_iterator`. `QVector`/`QList` also qualify, off the top of my head. So does `std::basic_string`. I will probably alter the body slightly, perhaps depending on the type of container and whatnot. But I need to cross this hurdle first.

Comment: @rubenvb: And what about containers that *aren't* templates? There's nothing that says a container type has to be generated from a template.

Answer (score 2):

This is hackish as hell and doesn't work with maps. I suggest rethinking your interface.

```
template<bool isAlloc, class From, class Of, class With>
struct rebind_arg { using type = From; };

template<bool isAlloc, class From, class Of, class With>
using rebind_arg_t = typename rebind_arg<isAlloc, From, Of, With>::type;

// allocators need to be rebound with allocator_traits
template<class From, class Of, class With>
struct rebind_arg<true, From, Of, With> { 
    using type = typename std::allocator_traits<From>::template rebind_alloc<With>; 
};

// Try to rebind non-allocator arguments
template<class T, class With>
struct rebind_arg<false, T, T, With> { using type = With; };

template<template<class...> class X, class T, class... Args, class With>
struct rebind_arg<false, X<Args...>, T, With> { 
    using type = X<rebind_arg_t<false, Args, T, With>...>; 
};

// resolve an ambiguity
template<template<class...> class X, class... Args, class With>
struct rebind_arg<false, X<Args...>, X<Args...>, With> { 
    using type = With; 
};

// Obtain the container's allocator type if it has one
template<class T, class=void>
struct get_allocator_type { struct none; using type = none; }; 

template<class T>
struct get_allocator_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::allocator_type>> { 
    using type = typename T::allocator_type; 
};

// Check if a type is the allocator type of another type
template<class T, class C>
constexpr bool is_allocator_of = std::is_same_v<T, typename get_allocator_type<C>::type>;

template<class C, class With>
struct rebind_container;

template<template<class...> class X, class... Args, class With>
struct rebind_container<X<Args...>, With> {
   using Source = X<Args...>;
   using type = X<rebind_arg_t<is_allocator_of<Args, Source>, Args,
                               typename Source::value_type, With>...>;
   static_assert(!std::is_same_v<Source, type>, "Rebinding unsuccessful");
};

template<class C, class With>
using rebind_container_t = typename rebind_container<C, With>::type;
```